# Avoiding third table in many to many relationship

Tags: sqlite

I want to create a sqlite database with at least two tables: account and service. One account can have several services and one service can be used by several accounts.

I would like to be able to query all the services which one account uses.

Now, where it gets complicated for me is that I would like to avoid a third table which is usually used - as far as I know - to resolve this many-to-many relationship.

Is there an appropriate way to do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can denormalize your schema and store relations in a field containing an array in each table. But this is going to be less efficient to query and not all database engines support array type. Actually sqlite3 doesn't. You can mitigate that by storing that as a JSON data type which will be then an array in JSON representation.